# XML not updating until cache is removed codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, caching

I am using codeigniter and I am having problem in refreshing xml file.I have a flash file that is connected to xml file.When I insert or edit something the xml file does not update until I clear the cache of the browser.I have tried to use 
 `header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");` but no success.Can anyone  help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in the HTML header:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```